# How to pass a Azure DevOps variable into a Postman value with Newman cli Companion?

Tags: variables, testing, azure-devops, environment-variables, postman

I have a Postman collection with environment and global variables. For security reasons I have my account credential in Azure DevOps Library as variable. With that credential I can recieve a token to use in my postman calls.

What I use now is the [Newman cli Companion for Postman](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=carlowahlstedt.NewmanPostman) and my .yml gives no errors:

```
task: NewmanPostman@4
    displayName: Run API Tests
    inputs:
       collectionFileSource: 'test.postman_collection.json'
       environment: 'test.postman_environment.json'            
       globalVars: 'Password=$(AAD-Password)'
```

I have set AAD-Password with the correct value in the DevOps library, in the .yml I set the globalvars: 'Password=$(AAD-password)' and in the collection I use {{Password}} as value to give a key that value.

[image]

The problem is that when I use it like this my password variable doesn't seem to be set as I get a 'invalid token' return which means the password which I set for the token doesn't seem to be set.
Does anyone now a different way to use a DevOps variable in a collection call or knows what I need to do different?

Comment: In the image, is the `Password` set with a Global Variable within the app? It looks like it's resolved by something.

Comment: @DannyDainton If I hover above it is an unresolved variable and turns red, as expected, with the message "this variable is not defined in the active collection, environment or globals"

Comment: Seems orange in that image  Were you using a global or environment variable in the app for that `Password` variable? Are you able to see what is actually getting sent as the password value, add some logging to the collection and view that in the Azure side. Does it send the correct value if you hardcode the value in the yml file?

Comment: It is indeed orange but when I hover it turns red so you are not going crazy :P I orginal had the Password variable as an environment variable but I checked everything and it does not exist anymore, also not in global hence the error message when I hover. 

I cannot however set the value hardcoded in the yml file as I don't have the rights to see the new password. Stupid question, is it even possible to log the value of password?  I tried 'console.log(pm.request.body.toString());' but that gives me "password={{Password}} and 'console.log("body : " + request.data);' says 'body:  object'

Comment: Something like this would probably work `console.log(pm.request.body.urlencoded.toObject())`

Comment: @DannyDainton Everything gets filled very nicely except {{Password}}.. Do you maybe know if I am using the newman CLI wrong and this just isn't possible?

Comment: That's what that Newman flag is for but the task is not using it directly that in exactly the same way though. I don't know what the expected syntax is for that task, I know what the Newman syntax is though but it also varies if you use the CLI or in a script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238654/discussion-between-efhk-and-danny-dainton).